Power BI Data source credentials to SQL Server failed
In Power BI premium workspace, I tried to connect to SQL Server via Data Source credential.
I can ping the server address, but always failed to connected in the Web.
You can see my config:

But after loading for a while, it shows the failure error:
I'm pretty sure the connection is correctly setup.


I don't know what the options are, but is Basic Auth correct for SQL Server?

does your connection to server is ok?

I'm not a PowerBI dev, but "Oracle" in your screen shot sticks out like a sore thumb, when you are saying you are trying to connect to SQL Server.

@HardCode oh, maybe the connection name misled you, that's just the name of the connection, and I need to connect to Oracle & MSSQL both.

@RF1991 Yes, I can use MSSQL studio to connect to the SQL Sever successfully, but weird that cannot connect to the server here.

@DaleK Cause I need to use DB username & pwd to connect, not to use my windows AD.

in powerbi, you can use both windows authentication and server authentication. use server authentication

@RF1991 hhhh, but the question is I don't have the Windows account, only one public read only account.
